Log-Log Regression versus Delta-Delta Regression
I am trying to estimate the self- and cross-price elasticities of demand for Alaska (AS) and Southwest (WN) on a given route. I have price in quantity data that varies over time.
Which of the following regression models should I use?
$$ \ln(\text{quantity}_{AS}) = b_0 + b_1 \cdot \ln(\text{price}_{AS}) + b_2 \cdot \ln(\text{price}_{WN}) + \text{demand_controls} $$
or
$$ \delta_{\text{quantity}_{AS}} = b_1 \cdot \delta_{\text{price}_{AS}} + b_2 \cdot \delta_{\text{price}_{WN}} + \delta_{\text{demand_controls}} $$
where
$$ \delta_x = \log(x_t) - \log(x_{t-1}). $$
My thinking is that the delta-delta model would be better at controlling for demand shifts, assuming that they are slow to occur. The log-log model wouldn't be affected by swapping the values of two time periods (e.g. swapping 2022Q1 with 2023Q1), but the delta-delta would be. Therefore the log-log model loses the time-based information.

fair question. I think you should worry more about endogeneity. Dont you think there is a feed back problem?
